# Infer expression from a string in Typescript

Tags: typescript

Given the code below, everything seems ok ([see playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACghsAFvATnAtgHgCoD4oC8U2UEAHsBAHYAmAzlAAYAkA3ncCgJZUDmAvgC42PAGYQUUAKr9GUAPzSogqFQgA3CQG4AUDtCRYcNOkJGkqDJgBEAejAB7DrcGOOAfS41ruLUA)):

```js
type PathParam<T> = T extends `${string}:${infer U}` ? U : never;

type Param = PathParam<"/post/:post_id">;
// type Param = "post_id"
```

But it gets a little bit complicated when there's additional text after the path param.

```js
type PathParam<T> = T extends `${string}:${infer U}` ? U : never;

type Param = PathParam<"/post/:post_id/likes/:like_id">;
// type Param = "post_id/likes/:like_id"
```

I can understand why it fails, but I'm not sure how can infer only the pattern `:${string}` in typescript. In regex it would be equivalent to `/:[a-z_]+/g`

So my question is - how can I make `Param` to be inferred as the following type?

```js
type Param = "post_id" | "like_id"
```

Comment: “All of the path params” means what, exactly?  What would you like `Param` to be in your second example, a union? A tuple? A concatenated string?

Comment: @jcalz sorry, I thought it was clear. I have updated my question

Comment: You can name this question to `infer query parameters`. It will be easier to find for folks

Comment: Btw, if you are interested in bizarre challenges in TS check out this repo https://github.com/type-challenges/type-challenges

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need recursive type to perform some loop to construct dynamic sized union.

try:

```
type PathParam<T extends string, Res extends string = never> = 
    T extends `${string}:${infer U}/${infer Rest}` 
    ?  U | PathParam<Rest, Res> :
    T extends `${string}:${infer L}` 
    ?  L : Res;
```